# Define function instance outside constructed class

Tags: c++, function, class, arduino

I am using the Arduino IDE and I'm trying to make executable commands. I have a class called command as so:

```
class Command {
    Command();
  public:
    void eval();
  private:
};

Command::Command() {}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
class Command {               // Create the command class
    Command();
  public:
    void eval();
  private:
};

Command::Command() {}        // Constructor

Command commandOne();           // Construct an instance of the class

void commandOne.eval() = () => {}     // Change eval function in class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `std::function` as a private member of your class and provide a setter to change it. Then implement your `eval` to call this function. Minimal example:

```
class Command
{
public:
  // note that constructor must be public
  Command(): _f() {}
  void eval()
  {
    if (_f)
    {
      _f();
    }
  }
  void setEval(std::function<void()> f)
  {
    _f = f;
  }
private:
  std::function<void()> _f;
};

int main()
{
  Command cmd;
  cmd.eval();
  cmd.setEval([]() { std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl; });
  cmd.eval();
  return 0;
}
```

If you don't want a setter and you know the body of your function before construction of `Command` object, you can delete the default constructor, remove the setter function, and implement `Command::Command(std::function<void()> f): _f(f) {}`.